# Items in one location not in another. SQL

Tags: sql, join

I'm trying to query, possibly with a self-join, to find which Products are on sale in Chicago that are not on sale in Miami.

```
ProductID           Product_Type  On Sale Stock_location
2201                   Cereal         Y   chicago
2202                   Beverage       Y   chicago
2203                   Frozen Food    y   chicago
2204                   Poultry        N   chicago
2205                   Health         N   chicago
2206                    Snacks        Y   chicago
2207                   Household      N   chicago
2208                   Personal       N   chicago
2209                   Produce        N   chicago
2201                    Cereal        Y   Miami
2202                    Beverage      Y   Miami
2203                    Frozen Food   N   Miami
2204                    Poultry       Y   Miami
2205                    Health        N   Miami
2206                   Snacks         Y   Miami
2207                    Household     N   Miami
2208                    Personal      N   Miami
```

Comment: By `Products` you mean `Product Types`, right?  Add the desired output to your question (use [Edit]).

Comment: What have you tried so far? What is the result of your own research, did you try to write this query? What was the problem with it? Would you mind to share what you have done so far? Please read [ask] in [help] for further guidance.

Comment: Similar questions have already been answered. A left join checking for null values in the joined table should make it. To avoid false positives check for a non nullable field (e.g. the primary key)

Comment: On a sidenote: If this is a table you are showing, the data model looks bad. The table suggests you can sell product 1234 as a cereal in Chicago and as a Beverage in Miami. Does this make sense? Shouldn't the product type be a column in the product table instead, so each product belongs to only one product type?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT t1.*
  FROM t AS t1
  JOIN t AS t2 ON ( t1.Product_Type = t2.Product_Type )
 WHERE t1.On_Sale = "Y"
   AND t2.On_Sale = "N";
```

Useful resource:
https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_self.asp

Answer (score 1):

It's something like below

```
select Product_Type from Products 
where [On Sale] = 'Y' and 
Stock_location = 'chicago' and 
Product_Type not in (Select Product_Type form Products where [On Sale] = 'N' and Stock_location = 'Miami' )
```